# Fitting mixture of Gamma variate functions at once (with python)

Tags: multiple-regression, python, gamma-distribution, curve-fitting, scipy

I am trying to automate the fitting of a signal composed of several **Gamma variate functions** with some added noise. However, I face some troubles and I do not know how to deal with it. First I do not know what solver to choose and why the ones I have tried fail (SLSQP, COBYLA, ...).

It is the first time I try to fit such a complex function. The fit is **highly sensitive** to the preset parameters (detected by interval segmentation using rupture), which does not make the method robust at all...

I guess the form of the function (with if and for loops) is also an issue... Maybe there is something better than scipy to do the job ? (such as CPLEX, Gurobi, Mosek, Xpress, etc.)

Any help is welcome !

Here is a part of the code output:

`raw signal:`

[image]

If I try to find the initial parameters like this:

```
def Initiate_Parameters(peaks):

    # Initiate the parameters based on the found curves
    params = np.zeros(4 * len(peaks))    
    for pk in range(len(peaks)):         
        # initial guesses
        params[pk * 4 + 0] = list(peaks)[pk]                    # tmax
        params[pk * 4 + 1] = peaks[params[pk * 4 + 0]] *0.7     # ymax
        params[pk * 4 + 2] = 1                                  # alpha
        params[pk * 4 + 3] = params[pk * 4 + 0] - 1000          # AT
    return params
```

Here is the results:

```
  • Initial Objective score: 486948083.344168
  • Final Objective score:   544857.2020755907
  • R² correlation = 0.9822807114129106
Solution for gamma cuvrve 1 :
  • tmax   = 56.0398491915798
  • ymax   = 289.60192865412944
  • alpha  = 23.09316050448387
  • AT     = -895.1055522009805
Solution for gamma cuvrve 2 :
  • tmax   = 233.33786128620045
  • ymax   = 455.3681441365064
  • alpha  = 70.95859468175692
  • AT     = -775.6995035505241
Solution for gamma cuvrve 3 :
  • tmax   = 598.2349150407774
  • ymax   = 482.0524394851544
  • alpha  = 34.893347990437825
  • AT     = -438.0504007789465
```

[image]

But if I decided to change the function to find initial parameters, affecting only AT:

```
def Initiate_Parameters(peaks):

    # Initiate the parameters based on the found curves
    params = np.zeros(4 * len(peaks))    
    for pk in range(len(peaks)):         
        # initial guesses
        params[pk * 4 + 0] = list(peaks)[pk]                    # tmax
        params[pk * 4 + 1] = peaks[params[pk * 4 + 0]] *0.7     # ymax
        params[pk * 4 + 2] = 1                                  # alpha
        params[pk * 4 + 3] = params[pk * 4 + 0] - 100           # AT

    return params
```

The result looks pretty different...

```
  • Initial Objective score: 46560853.304969855
  • Final Objective score:   19519888.326930575
  • R² correlation = 0.5703701950750049
Solution for gamma cuvrve 1 :
  • tmax   = 102.18255199219803
  • ymax   = 324.16745138185007
  • alpha  = 2.074917963036321
  • AT     = 2.7375869275750824
Solution for gamma cuvrve 2 :
  • tmax   = 226.67108538687984
  • ymax   = 487.43411063438265
  • alpha  = 1.0056653550394392
  • AT     = 125.87136501547698
Solution for gamma cuvrve 3 :
  • tmax   = 347.90715935325585
  • ymax   = 390.6541617771044
  • alpha  = 0.1685425172833932
  • AT     = 245.32587623362775
```

[image]

Here is the code:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Nov  5 15:11:38 2019

@author: ancollet
"""

import numpy as np
from math import exp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import ruptures as rpt
from scipy import stats

def Gamma_Variate_Function_Madsen(t, tmax, ymax, alpha, AT):

    """
    Madsen, M. T., “A simplified formulation of the gamma variate function,
    ”Physics in Medicine and Biol-ogy37(7), 1597–1600 (1992).    

    "The fit of the gamma variate function has been used in numerous studies. 
    The main benefitsof the gamma variate function are the convenient 
    mathematical properties.  
    We found that the fitting of the gamma variate function leads to problems 
    because of the slow ”wash out” of the bolus".

    t: time value
    tmax: time of the peak
    ymax: peak intensity (absolute value)
    alpha: shape parameter
    AT: appearance time --> should be lower that tmax

    """
    if t <= AT:
        return 0
    if tmax <= AT:
        return float('nan')

    #t should always be positive
    t = abs((t - AT) / (tmax - AT))
    #print(t)
    f = ymax * pow(t, alpha) * exp(alpha * (1 - t))

    return f


def Multiple_Gamma_Variate_Function_Madsen(t, params):

    """
    Madsen, M. T., “A simplified formulation of the gamma variate function,
    ”Physics in Medicine and Biol-ogy37(7), 1597–1600 (1992).    

    t: time value
    tmax: time of the peak
    ymax: peak intensity (absolute value)
    alpha: shape parameter
    AT: appearance time --> should be lower that tmax

    """

    f = 0

    for i in range(int(len(params)/4)):
        tmax = params[i*4] 
        ymax = params[i*4 + 1]
        alpha = params[i*4 + 2]
        AT = params[i*4 + 3]

        if t <= AT:
            f += 0
        elif tmax <= AT:
            f += 0
        else:
            #t should always be positive
            t2 = abs((t - AT) / (tmax - AT))
            #print(t)
            f += ymax  * pow(t2, alpha) * exp(alpha * (1 - t2))
    return f

# define objective function: SSE
def Objective_Fun(params, y_raw):

    # calculate y
    # calculate objective
    obj = 0.0
    for t in range(1, len(y_raw)):
        if y_raw[t] != 0: #and not isnan(y_raw[t]):
            y_fit = Multiple_Gamma_Variate_Function_Madsen(t, params)
            obj = obj + (y_fit-y_raw[t])**2
    # return result
    return obj

def Moving_Average(a, n=3) :
    ret = np.cumsum(a, dtype=float)
    ret[n:] = ret[n:] - ret[:-n]
    return ret[n - 1:] / n

def Detect_Multiple_Gamma_Breakpoints(signal, n_bkps = 1, min_size = 10, 
                                      jump = 1, model = 'rbf',
                                      pen = 1):

    # Need to ensure a numpy array
    signal = np.array(signal)

    # Smoothing (to get rid of the noise), getting the base and removing it
    signal_smooth = Moving_Average(signal, n = min_size)    

    # change point detection: Window segmentation
    algo = rpt.Window(width = min_size, model=model).fit(signal_smooth)

    # predict the ruptures with a given number of breakpoints
    breakpoints = algo.predict(n_bkps)

    # display the results
    rpt.display(signal, breakpoints)
    plt.plot(signal_smooth)
    plt.show()


    return breakpoints

def Find_Multiple_Gamma_Peaks_2(signal, n_peaks):

    # Case with only a single Gamma variate:
    if n_peaks == 1:
        i_max, j_max = 0, 0
        for i, j in enumerate(signal):
            if j > j_max:
                j_max = j
                i_max = i
        peaks_indices = {i_max: j_max}
        return peaks_indices

    # Else: Two Gamma to fit at least
    peaks_indices = {}

    #Detect the breakpoints in the series
    breakpoints = \
    Detect_Multiple_Gamma_Breakpoints(y_raw, n_bkps = n_peaks - 1, 
                                      min_size = 40, jump = 1, model = 'rbf',
                                      pen = 1)

    i1 = 0
    # Iterate over breakpoints
    for i2 in breakpoints:
        # Take the interval between breakpoints
        sub_signal = signal[i1 + 1 : i2 - 1]
        # Add the max of this sub_signal to the peak_index dico
        peak_index = \
        [i + i1 + 1 for i, j in enumerate(sub_signal) if j == max(sub_signal)]
        peaks_indices[peak_index[0]] = signal[peak_index[0]]
        # Set the lower bound for the next iteration as the current 
        # interval upperbound
        i1 = i2

    return peaks_indices

def Fit_TS_Multiple_Gamma_Variates(y_raw, n_peaks):

    # Find the peaks
    peaks = Find_Multiple_Gamma_Peaks_2(y_raw, n_peaks)
    # Initiate a preset of parameters from the peaks found
    params_raw = Initiate_Parameters(peaks)
    # cons = f(nb of peaks)
    cons = Initiate_Parameters_Constraints(peaks)
    # bonds = f(nb of peaks)
    bnds = Initiate_Parameters_Bounds(peaks)

    tol = 1e-7

    """
    #Solving
    solution = minimize(Objective_Fun, x0 = params, method='CG', bounds=bnds,
                        args = (y_raw), constraints = None)
    """

    """
    #Solving
    solution = minimize(Objective_Fun, x0 = params, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds,
                        args = (y_raw), constraints = cons)

    """

    # Solving
    solution = minimize(Objective_Fun, x0 = params_raw, method='COBYLA', 
                        bounds=bnds, args = (y_raw), tol = tol)

    # Get the optimized parameters
    params_fit = solution.x

    # Generate the fitted curve (general + individual)
    y_fits = Get_Y_Fits(y_raw, params_fit, n_peaks)

    return y_fits, params_raw, params_fit

def Get_Y_Fits(y_raw, params, n_peaks):

    # Store the curves as a dico
    y_fits = {}

    y_fit = np.zeros(len(y_raw))
    for t in range(len(y_raw)):
        y_fit[t] = Multiple_Gamma_Variate_Function_Madsen(t, params)

    y_fits['Global gamma fit curve'] = y_fit

    if n_peaks > 1:
        for pk in range(1, n_peaks + 1):
            y_fit = np.zeros(len(y_raw))
            sub_params = params[(pk - 1) * 4: pk * 4] 
            #print(sub_params)
            for t in range(len(y_raw)):
                y_fit[t] = \
                Multiple_Gamma_Variate_Function_Madsen(t, sub_params)
            y_fits['Gamma fit cruve ' + str(pk)] = y_fit

    return y_fits


def Initiate_Parameters(peaks):

    # Initiate the parameters based on the found curves
    params = np.zeros(4 * len(peaks))    
    for pk in range(len(peaks)):         
        # initial guesses
        params[pk * 4 + 0] = list(peaks)[pk]                    # tmax
        params[pk * 4 + 1] = peaks[params[pk * 4 + 0]] * 0.7    # ymax
        params[pk * 4 + 2] = 1                                  # alpha
        params[pk * 4 + 3] = params[pk * 4 + 0] - 1000          # AT

    return params

def Initiate_Parameters_Constraints(peaks):

    #Empty list
    cons = []
    #Setting the constraints as dictionnaries
    for pk in range(len(peaks)):
        cons.append({'type': 'ineq', 
                     'fun': lambda x: x[pk * 4 + 0] - x[pk * 4 + 3]})
    return cons

def Initiate_Parameters_Bounds(peaks):

    bnds = ()
    for pk in range(len(peaks)):        
        # bounds on variables
        # tmax belongs to R
        # ymax belongs to R+
        # alpha belongs to R+
        # AT belongs to R
        bnds += ((-10000, 10000), (0, 5000), (0, 50), (-10000, 10000))

    return bnds

def Get_Variance_Explaination_R2(y_raw, y_fit):

    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = \
    stats.linregress(y_raw, y_fit)
    r2 = r_value**2

    return r2

def Display(r2, params_raw, params_fit):

    # show initial objective
    print('  • Initial Objective score: ' \
          + str(Objective_Fun(params_raw, y_raw)))

    # show final objective
    print('  • Final Objective score:   ' \
          + str(Objective_Fun(params_fit, y_raw)))

    cR2 = "  • R² correlation = " + str(r2)

    print(cR2)

    n_peaks = int(len(params_fit)/4)

    for pk in range(n_peaks):
        # print solution
        print('Solution for gamma cuvrve', str(pk + 1), ':')
        ctmax =  '  • tmax   = ' + str(params_fit[pk * 4])
        print(ctmax)
        cymax =  '  • ymax   = ' + str(params_fit[pk * 4 + 1])
        print(cymax)
        calpha = '  • alpha  = ' + str(params_fit[pk * 4 + 2])
        print(calpha)
        cAT =    '  • AT     = ' + str(params_fit[pk * 4 + 3])
        print(cAT)

#Test
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Generate a multi - Gamma variate curve
    x_raw = range(1000)

    params = [100, 450, 0.9, -100, 250, 300, 1.2, 100, 600, 300, 2, 400]
    y_raw = [Multiple_Gamma_Variate_Function_Madsen(x, params) + \
             float(np.random.normal(0,2,1)) for x in x_raw]
    #y_raw = [Multiple_Gamma_Variate_Function_Madsen(x, params) for x in x_raw]

    #Show the raw curve
    print('raw signal:')
    plt.plot(y_raw) #.fig_title = 'Raw noisy data'
    plt.show()

    # Fit successively with one, two and then three Gamma - Variate
    for n_peaks in [1, 2, 3]:

        print('Fitting the curve with ', n_peaks, ' Gamma functions...')

        #Fit the functions
        y_fits, params_raw, params_fit = \
        Fit_TS_Multiple_Gamma_Variates(y_raw, n_peaks)

        #Calculate R2
        r2 = \
        Get_Variance_Explaination_R2(y_raw, y_fits['Global gamma fit curve'])

        #Display the regression parameters and info:
        Display(r2, params_raw, params_fit)

        #Plot the results
        plt.plot(y_raw)        
        for key in y_fits.keys():
            plt.plot(y_fits[key])
        plt.show()
```

Comment: Exactly what is the problem? Your illustration looks like a success, not a failure.  The concern about robustness is legitimate, because mixture models are notoriously difficult to fit and unstable.  Are you perhaps fishing for information on making the model more robust?  Or maybe on how to identify good starting values for the solution?

Comment: You are right, this is not very clear... I updated my question.
The main issue is that I want to apply the code to real data, with noise and other parameters affecting the distribution. Here is a perfect mixture of distribution, with very little noise. The model should be able to handle it whatever the initial parameters are right ?

Comment: Mathematically the model can accommodate any data, but as a practical matter that's expecting far too much.  Even in simpler cases it may be impossible to discover the global minimum of the objective function automatically.

Comment: I found a solver which is working quite well (but takes a bit too much time):
```    #Solving
    solution = minimize(Objective_Fun, x0 = params_raw, method='trust-constr', bounds = bnds_t, args = (y_raw), constraints = cons)
```
Now I need to have a look to deconvolution techniques to speed-up the process. I will update my post with some results from the lastest solver.